# $\lim_{x\to\infty}2^{-x}$ ( epsilon-delta)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

I want to prove that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}{2^{-x}}=0$.

$\ln(2^{-x})=-x\ln(2)$ so, I define $M=-\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(2)}$

Then,

$x>M=-\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(2)}$

$\therefore -x\ln(2)\lt\ln(\epsilon)$

$\therefore|2^{-x}|<\epsilon$


Is this proof  right?

Comment: Write the statement you are proving here, which is $\lim_{x \to \infty} 2^{-x}=0$.

Comment: Yes, this is absolutely right. Just write it in proper way.

Comment: A common statement to make is "let $\epsilon\gt 0$ be given, then...".  This establishes a meaning for $\epsilon$ so that your definition of $M$ makes sense...

Comment: You need to write like this: For every $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists a number $M=-\frac{\ln(\epsilon)}{\ln(2)}$ such that if  $x\gt M$ then $|2^{-x}-0|<\epsilon$. Therefore $lim_{x\to\infty}{2^{-x}}=0$

Comment: Have you seen how to write an epsilon delta proof more formally? Could you do an easier example and then rewrite your proof more formally?